# R - Extract string from a text document

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

How do I extract the string after some digits + a semi colon and period? For example:

Input:

```
Ahbbfksjsbsshbd
1234: hello.
7273: goodbye.
Hrjsbshdhf
```

Output:

```
1234: hello.
7273: goodbye.
```

(Stored in two different rows)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far?  Check out the `stringr` package.

Comment: Do you mean "colon"? There are no semi-colons (`;`) in your data. Probably `grepl("^[0-9]+[:;].*\\.$",x)`

Comment: http://www.endmemo.com/program/R/grepl.php is the function you are looking for. You will need to modify the regex string based on what the rest of your data looks like - with messy data there is no silver bullet

Comment: Using str_extract(x, "[0-9]{4}:.*\\.") outputs "1234: hello. 7273: goodbye" now I just have to split these two and stor separately

Answer (score 0):

You can match this kind of strings with [this](https://regex101.com/r/dty9NF/3) regex:

```
^\d+:\s*\w+\.
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
/^\d+:.*\.$/gm
```

The items of interest would be in `$0`

https://regex101.com/r/olgMxj/2